# Swift: Parsing Arrays out of JSONs

Tags: arrays, json, swift

```
[{"name":"Air Elemental","toughness":"4","printings":["LEA","BTD","7ED","8ED","9ED","10E","DD2","M10","DPA","ME4","DD3_JVC"]}]
```

I have a JSON where there is an array in each listing called "printings" as seen below, how would I take this array out of each listing and convert it into a string like "LEA-BTD-7ED". Here is what I have so far but its crashing.

```
let err : NSErrorPointer?
    let dataPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cardata", ofType: "json")
    let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: dataPath! as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)
    do{
        var contents = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [AnyObject]

        for var i = 0;i<contents.count;++i{

                let printing = contents[i]["printings"] as! String
                 }
        }
```

Comment: What does your crash or error tell you?

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x107833d68) to 'NSString' (0x10888bb48).   I know its because I'm trying to turn the array into a string

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
let path = dataPath!
if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
{
    do
    {
        if let dictionariesArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as?
            [[String: AnyObject]]
        {
            for dictionary in dictionariesArray
            {
                if let printingsArray = dictionary["printings"] as? [String]
                {
                    let printingsString = printingsArray.joinWithSeparator("-")
                    print(printingsString)
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        print("Could not parse file at \(path)")
    }
}
```

Executing it prints "LEA-BTD-7ED-8ED-9ED-10E-DD2-M10-DPA-ME4-DD3_JVC"

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an `Array` (`contents[i]["printings"]`) to a `String`. What you want is `Array`'s `joinWithSeparator()` method, like this:

```
let printing = contents[i]["printing"] as! Array
let printingStr = printing.joinWithSeparator("-")
```

(Actually, I'm not sure whether you need the `as! Array`; try it without it.)

Comment: doing without array doesn't work because it thinks its a segmentation error. Doing it with array causes a segmentation error for some reason.

Comment: Hmm. Does `contents[i]` need to be cast as a `Dictionary` first? How does it know what type is which?

Comment: Tried that as well. The problem is, I can't convert any object to array

Comment: Oh, duh--`NSJSONSerialization` produces `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s, not the Swift `Array` and `Dictionary` objects. Cast it to one of those.